# How to ensure Maven downloaded jars method is not showing while clicking on the method name in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When I click on the method name to see its details in eclipse, I want to see only those methods details, classes of which that I have created manually and not the details of the jar that maven has downloaded.

What setting should i do in eclipse to ensure this happens?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: Sure, i will add the screen shot.